# How to reduce width of dataset in group bar chart which used chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chartjs-2.6.0

How to reduce width of dataset in group bar chart which used chartjs.
In the screenshot I have shown which width I need to reduce in red line.
Better if we can do this using chartjs itself, if not other alternatives also welcome.
I refer to this library http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

[Red line shows which width I need to reduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiZzj.png)

Comment: What all have you tried? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

That attribute stored in x-axis, you just need to configure x-axis just like below

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            categoryPercentage: 1.5
        }]
    }
}
```

```js
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Sample Dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)",
        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 75, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                // Change here
                barPercentage: .5,
               categoryPercentage: 1.5
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
```